# Parse JSON object to Django template

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to parse a JSON object to Django template so that I can parse this json object to javascript.

Here how my view creates and parse the json object to the template:

```
    countries = Country.objects.filter(Enabled=True)
    citiesByCountry = {}

    for country in countries:
        citiesInCountry = City.objects.filter(Enabled=True, Country=country)
        cities = []

        for city in citiesInCountry:
            cities.append(city.Name)

        citiesByCountry[country.Name] = cities

    context = {'citiesByCountry': json.dumps(citiesByCountry)}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Now I would like to retrieve all the keys (which will be countries) to my template this way:

```
{% for country in citiesByCountry%}
   <option>{{ country }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

But what I get is an option for each character in strings instead of the country name as a whole.

I tried to use `.item1` but this didn't work either.

I don't show JavaScript code in my example above as the intent of the question is how to parse and retrieve strings from a JSON object. I need to process this data using javascript later. In specific once the user change country I would like to populate another dropdown that will handle the cities, and therefore I thought to use JSON and Javascript to achieve that, as I don't want to refresh the page on each change.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you need to parse it to javascript? In your example you are not doing that

Comment: Why are you encoding `citiesByCountry` to JSON? Just pass it as a dict to context like `context = {'citiesByCountry': citiesByCountry}` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't show JavaScript code in my example above as the intent of the question is how to parse and retrieve strings from a JSON object. I need to process this data using javascript later. In specific once the user change country I would like to populate another dropdown that will handle the cities, and therefore I thought to use JSON and Javascript to achieve that, as I don't want to refresh the page on each change.

Comment: @xyres I did what you said and works in the past, but now that I want to populate the city dropdown list using JavaScript, I am not sure if I can parse a Python List to javascript.

Comment: @John In that case, Django's template syntax won't work. You'll have to do it completely in JS.

Answer (score 4):

To answer you question in the title:

In `<head>` (or somewhere), build your array of counties:

```
<script>
    var country_objs = [];
    {% for country in citiesByCountry%}
        country_objs.push({{country|escapejs}});
    {% endfor %}
<\script>
```

Docs for the filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

Then you can use it in JavaScript (but not in Django template). For example:

```
<select id="cities"><\select>
<script>
    var $cities_select = $("#cities");
    $(country_objs).each(function(){
        $cities_select.append('<option value="' + this.id_or_something + '">' + this.name + '<\option>');
    });
<\script>
```

But from your example I don't see why you need to encode it in JSON in the first place. Why not just pass a dict into the template (via context, just as everything else)?

P.S.
Sorry for using jQuery, l'm just lazy :)

Comment: @John Ah, comments contain additional explanation about why JSON. Perhaps make an edit to your question. For future generations, you know ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. I will give a try to your solution and I will let you know.

Comment: I think that worked. But for some reason the city value is 'Undefined' which I guess has something to do with this line `$cities_select.append('<option>' + this.Name + '<\option>');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1. Parse the JSON in the `<option>` tags with javascript.

   ```
   <script>
       var json = JSON.parse({{citiesByCountry}});
       //Loop through json and append to <option>
   </script>
   ```
2. Add an extra `context` that isn't JSON serialized. This is a little redundant but a bit simpler.

   ```
   context = {'citiesByCountry_json': json.dumps(citiesByCountry), 'citiesByCountry': citiesbyCountry}
   ```

To be honest, I'd go for the second option since I don't see why you need to send it to the template in JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `citiesByCountry = json.dumps({'a': "b", 'c': None})`, `citiesByCountry` is a string. This is why you get character after character when you iterate over it.

This string representing a JSON object, you can "affect" as-is to a JavaScript variable:

```
var citiesByCountry = {{ citiesByCountry }};
```

Which will output something like:

```
var citiesByCountry = {"a": "c", "d": null};
```

However, considering what you want to achieve:

> In specific once the user change country I would like to populate another dropdown that will handle the cities

I highly recommend you to checkout [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/), which in addition to providing auto-completion, provides a way to [filter results based on other fields](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form). This will save you much efforts.